# How can i show a number of hidden selectboxes from selected option

Tags: jquery

if i choose from a selectbox an option, then should be shown mor selectboxes like the selected index is given.
I hope you understand me.

```
var $heidi = $('#add_select label');

$('#children').change(function(){
  var  $select = this.selectedIndex;

  $heidi.fadeOut('3000');

  $('#add_select label:gt($select)').fadeIn('3000');//why dont this work?

 }).trigger('change');
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: `$('#add_select label:gt('+$select+')')` - u missed the quotes around `$select` and u neednt `trigger` the `change` event

Comment: hi, ok but if someone change the option twice or more times only bigger values will be shown it doesnt count from the beginning. What i have to do? thank you!

Comment: could you make a fiddle for this @ jsfiddle.net? it'll hepl solve the problem quicker

Comment: hi http://bit.ly/1aVBoPP

Comment: This selectboxes are in a form-element with validation after submit. if validation failed the checkboxes are empty and all 5 are shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide all the `<select>`s before you show what you need :

```
var $hideSelect = $('#add_select .chld-bx');
$hideSelect.hide();
$('#children').change(function () {
    $hideSelect.hide();
    var $select = this.selectedIndex;
    $hideSelect.filter(':lt(' + $select + ')').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/CqD9r/8/